# When can constexpr variables be implicitly captured by contexpr lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, constexpr

```
#include <array>

template<typename F>
constexpr auto call(const F& visitor)
{
    return visitor();
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int x = 10;
    constexpr std::array y = { 1, 2, 3};

    static_assert(call([]{ return x + 10; }) == 20);
    static_assert(call([]{ return y[0] + 10; }) == 11);
}
```

The following code doesn't compile because the array is not accesible from the 2nd lambda. Why is the constexpr int available in the first lambda without capturing, but not the array in the 2nd? Aren't they both available without having to capture? Why does the array have to be captured if it is constexpr (which will make my lambda a non-constexpr lambda because of the capture)?

Comment: Doesnt seem to compile on clang https://godbolt.org/z/8faqYvxPW

Comment: Compiles fine on VS2019, now that the extra paren was removed.

Comment: VS seems to be the only one then can't get GCC clang etc to compile it.

Comment: Discussion of clang bug here: https://reviews.llvm.org/D92733  Looks like a bug as it should compile. Don't need a capture default for these.

Comment: Oddly, it works fine on my VS2019 but not on godbolt's MSVC. Weird

Comment: The sane explanation of constexpr of C++14 was for whatever reason removed by C++17 and broken dim wording was also applied back to previous standards. Now only some of it happens to work similarly on different C++ compilers (or versions of such by same supplier).

Comment: This is only confusing me more :P, is it supposed to compile? I mean I geuss because it's constexpr you could always make it static but that has other implications again for optimization that seem to be harder to take care of.

Comment: While it's legal and should compile, these sorts of corner cases aren't always well tested by compiler vendors. You can always just declare them const and capture them. Or file a bug report. It's a good question/problem.

Comment: Capturing anything will make the lambda a non-constexpr lambda.

Comment: Captures prevent conversion to function pointers, but by themselves do not preclude being constexpr.

Comment: Yeah. good point. You could always make it a constexpr external function. I've had to do that in the past when bugs showed up. Compilers sure have improved in the last few years though overall.

Comment: I'm trying to make a type erased constexpr function view type, that can optionally behave as function pointer when used in constexpr context.

Comment: Isn't the answer here just that x isn't odr-used in the lambda and y is odr-used?